# Intermittent image link behaviour in iOS mail client

Tags: iphone, html, ios, email, hyperlink

First of all, apologies if this is in the wrong site, it's not specifically a development, admin or other specific issue.

I've had to test sending HTML emails with "Image Links" on a variety of platforms due to an issue reported to me where people have been experiencing intermittant issues clicking those links with the iPhone mail client.

The test mail is very simple, along these lines:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="something.png"/>
</a>
```

When the mail arrives and I click on the link, I get the following popup rather than the client following the link. As you can see, the URL is displayed in the popup so clearly it's being parsed correctly.

[image: Screenshot of popup]

However, **intermittently** it will work! I can't quite pin down exactly what's causing it to work, but approximately 20% of the time it will (even the same email that has previously failed to work).

What gives? am I loosing my marbles? Is this some kind of iOS security feature to prevent spammers hiding links in emails?

The mail is delivered via an Exchange active-sync account.

Many Thanks

Comment: We experienced the problem yesterday as well but haven't found a solution (yet). Same mail always works on iPad. We will start comparing iOS Versions and post insights here.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I only have iOS 5.1 devices to test with myself. I have old iOS versions in the simulator but you can't really test mail on that. Hmm..

Comment: We tested four iPhones and the problem occurs on iOS 5.1 with iPhone "4" only. Other combinations all work, including a "3GS" with iOS 5.1

Comment: You'll find that it works if Safari is already open (with a page to that site?).  It's clearly an iOS bug.

Comment: And also only cid: images it seems.

Comment: Same issue with HTML emails. The images display, but clicking on them popup some weird menu (images are wrapped inside `<a>` tags, images are embedded `cid:` images).

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that the image map technique works....

I'd never used it before, but then we are dealing with apple here so we all have to bend over to their ways (mac owner of 10yrs speaking here).

```
<img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web2/Icons/FaceBook_128x128.png" alt="Facbook" usemap="#facebook" />
```

Simply reference usemap="#facebook" in the img tag and then set map name tag and properties...

```
<map name="facebook">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,128,128" href="http://www.facebook.com" alt="Facebook" />
</map>
```

(ps coords="x,y,w,h")

Obviously don't duplicate the same usemap references in the same document.

As discussed here -
[Image link on iPhone is not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502045/image-link-on-iphone-is-not-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since questions about the status of this issue are being deleted, I'll try it with a reference to a : [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502045/image-link-on-iphone-is-not-clickable)

Edit: It seems that the solution with the HTML-Map works on the iPhone 4 (iOS 5.1.1) and the iPad 3. But it seems that it does not work on Android-Devices... but this is not in the scope of this issue here anyway.

If the solution also works on older iOS versions I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

We have found a new detail to this problem. In our mails are also "Text Links". If we try to open a "Image Link" the save and copy appears, but if we first click a "Text Link", which works perfectly fine, go back to the mail and click the "Image Link" it mysteriously works. It seems that somehow the mail-client cannot open a connection to Safari through a "Image Link" click. If the connection is already open (through "Text Link" click) it works.