# Why anchors tag containing an image don't work in Iphone's mail app?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, anchor, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I"m doing a HTML newsletter for a client, using thunderbird to send it, and everything works fine in all browsers and mail clients, but the anchor tag containing an image, don't work in Iphone's mail app. Every time i click the image, the app ask me if i want to download the image, It doesn't take the "href".

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had this same issue - iPhone/iPad Apple mail app treating linked images as photos, not opening up in Safari as intended. Other mobile devices worked fine, as well as desktop computer tests.

Fix: upload the images in question to your server before testing on mobile devices.

After uploading the images to our server, the images were then recognised as links by iMail app on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Had the problem with embedded images, linked once are working properly