# How to make an image Clickable for iPhone to make a call

Tags: html, iphone, image, call

Is that possible to let an image clickable (in email) in order to call a phone number?

I tried

```
<a href=\"tel:1234567\"><img src=\"image1.png\" alt=\"test\" /></a>
```

and

```
<img src=\"cid:image1\" alt=\"test\" usemap=\"#testImage\"   />
<map name=\"testImage\"><area shape=\"rect\" coords=\"0,0,480,200\"
href=\"tel:1234567 \" alt=\"testimage\" /></map></td></tr>
```

The code above is from C# code behind. 
They are not working...

Comment: Would you like to share some code?

Comment: What format did you use for the link? (`<a href="tel:+0123456789"><img ... /></a>`, or ?)

Comment: Yes, use this: on touchevent on imageview NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

Comment: Hi @Rob, that's right. not in HTML. In C# code like, message.Body = "...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Justin Cherniak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015076/1271826) to this other question worked for me.

Thus (obviously, back-slash escape the quotation marks as you put this in your C++ code):

```
<a href="tel:+12125551212">
  <img src="http://foo/bar.png" usemap="linkmap" alt="Click me" title="Click me"/>
  <map name="linkmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,80,80" href="tel:+12125551212" alt="Click me" />
  </map>
</a>
```