# Image link is not clickable in responsive view

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

I am using bootstrap in my markup . My mark is simple , it looks like this

```
   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2  col-md-offset-1 logo">
        <a href="www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/new/header_logo.png" alt="Test"/>            
        </a>
   </div>
```

It works fine in desktop , when I click to the image it takes me to google.com . But it doesn't work on responsive view . In responsive view if I click on the image it does nothing .

I have also tried like this

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2  col-md-offset-1 logo">
  <a href="www.google.com">
    <img src=images/new/header_logo.png" alt="Test" usemap="#maptest"/> 
  </a>
</div>
<map name="maptest">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,128,128" href="www.google.com" alt="Test"/>
</map>
```

Also I have checked the following stackoverflow question , it doesn't solve my problem

[Image link on iPhone is not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502045/image-link-on-iphone-is-not-clickable)

Comment: in responsive view there might be an unwanted div comes on top of the image. when you touch the screen the div is selected instead of the image or the anchor. Try to check what i mentioned.

Comment: I have checked my document , it my markup is validated by w3c

Comment: what i mean is when the screen is smaller, other div(s) in side your code which are not response to the screen comes on top. may be because of the unwanted width or the height. you can check this on the ipad rotating to landscape mode or touch and hold the image for a while to give the pop up to save the image in landscape and portrait mode. if the pop up is not coming then definitely image is covered by a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question , I add z-index to the element I want to click

```
   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2  col-md-offset-1 logo">
        <a href="www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/new/header_logo.png" alt="Test"/>            
        </a>
   </div>

.logo {
   z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the image has covered by an element as i mention earlier.